# How to mathematically describe sampling from a CDF?

Tags: random, sampling

Is there a concise way to mathematically write the following statement:

> $\zeta$ is a randomly sampled value from a cumulative distribution
>   function $F_X$ of a random variable $X$.

$\zeta~=~?$

More precisely, I want to have a function $\Psi$ that associates each element from a set $S$ with a randomly sampled value from a given CDF $F_X$.

$\Psi : S~\to~?$

Thanks in advance for your answer(s).

NS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would say $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ are independent and identically distributed samples from the distribution whose CDF is $F_X.$ It is ok for this sequence to be infinite. If $\xi$ is one of these samples and you want to write $\xi=?,$ you need to say which one and write $\xi =X_i.$ If you want each element of the set $S$ to be associated with one of the $X_i,$ (presumably uniquely) then let $A =\{X_1,X_2,\ldots\}$ and consider one to one functions $S\to A.$

The issue is that “a random sample” is underspecified, at least it is when there are multiple random samples under consideration. But we have a mathematically precise way of defining a sequence of iid samples, and we can proceed to treat the random variables in that sequence as ordinary mathematical objects.

If there is a name for the distribution, like $N(0,1),$ it is common to abbreviate like $$X\sim N(0,1)$$ for a single sample or $$ X_i \sim_{i.i.d.} N(0,1)$$ for an independent identically distributed sequence. I wouldn’t consider it too grave an abuse of notation to substitute $F_X$ for $N(0,1),$ effectively naming the distribution by its CDF.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications. From what I understand, I think it is simply not possible to associate each element of, e.g., a set A = {a1,a2,a3} with random samples {X1,X2,X3} without specifying the process of sampling from the CDF (exactly how we got the samples). Is this correct? Maybe, as you suggest, should I just write zeta follows Fx. My issue lays in that I don't want to explain part of the process in plain text rather than formulas, and it seems that there is most likely not a concise way to do it.

Comment: Well I think when you said it there it was pretty clear what you meant. Certain aspects of the process are important and others aren’t. For instance you probably mean for the samples to be independent and should say so. I think a sentence like “to each element $a\in A,$ we associate an independent sample $X_a$ from the distribution with CDF $F_X$“ is pretty clear. What’s going on underneath is that we have a sequence that we’re matching up with $A,$ but that need not be said to give a clear picture.